# the event fired by server

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

My server is firing an event to client2 on some request by client1.The fired event is captured correctly by client2.

See the below code:

```
'experimentService.experimentPermissionChangedByOwner subscribe': function(eventName, event){

            if(this.resource.id == event.eventData.resource) {
                if (event.eventData.permissionType == "unshare") {  
                    message = this.resource.name +" has been unshared by the owner: "+event.eventData.ownerUsername+". "+messagePart2;
                    this.openWorkspaceObject({id: event.eventData.dashboardId, namespace: "bjkbb", type: "jhvhhkk" });
                }
                else {
                    message = "Owner: "+event.eventData.ownerUsername+" changed permission of "+ this.resource.name +" to "+ event.eventData.permissionType +". ";
                    if (event.eventData.permissionType == "view") {
                        message += messagePart2;
                    }
                    this.publish("elements.atlas.resource-page-modified", this.resource); 
                }

                this.openDialog({
                    dialogClass: elements.AlertCollaborators,
                    message: message
                });
            }

        this.publish("event.ack", {eventId: event.id});
    },
```

The above code is going to create a small dialog box with a message. Now the problem is on refreshing the browser, it again goes into the subscribe function. I dnt know how to handle this? Moroever after putting debug points I saw that it does not go into publish for this method. Then how does the subcribe capture it again??

Comment: It does not go into the publish method on refresh of browser. It goes the first time its required to go.

Comment: Does the browser store the most recent client event...and render it again on refresh?

Comment: can me make a event captured dead immediately once we capture it?